# The strange behavior of this

Tags: javascript

There is here such code, I do not understand why the output "Hello"? The idea is to `g: bind (f, "Hello")` should return a wrapper function that calls the function `f` the context of the "Hello". Accordingly, `this` function `f` should point to the `global object`.

```
function bind(func, context, args) {
    var bindArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 2); // (1)

    function wrapper() { // (2)
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var unshiftArgs = bindArgs.concat(args); // (3)
        return func.apply(context, unshiftArgs); // (4)
    }

    return wrapper;
}


function f() {
    alert( this );
}

var user = {
    g: bind(f, "Hello")
}

user.g();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think the context would be the global object. If you could explain your rationale, somebody may be able to offer a more precise explanation.

Comment: Note that `func.apply(context)` is the same as `func.apply('Hello')` in your code, so Pointy is right as usual, the `thisArg` is set to the string `Hello`

Comment: In ECMAScript, the term "context" is used for [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). A function's *this* is one parameter of its execution context. The variable name *context* would be better as *thisArg*, as used in the specification (e.g. [*§10.4.3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the context won't be the global context, it'll be the string "Hello".  The context is the second argument to your `bind()` function, so that'll be the value of `this` when function "f" is called.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov ?? String objects and string primitives can be kind-of hard to tell apart; try `alert(typeof this)` and see what it says. Otherwise I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov OK yes, that fiddle shows the way it works.

Comment: I just saw when I thought that this is complete nonsense, as the function is called in the context of string. But now he understood why.

Comment: And you luck. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In non–strict mode, if the value supplied as *this* is not an object and is not *null* or *undefined*, it will be converted to an object.

So *this* within *f* will be a String object whose internal value is "Hello", see [*ECMA-262 §10.4.3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3).

If you change:

```
alert( this );
```

to the following, which shows the internal *class* of an object so can tell what type of Object it is:

```
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(this) ); // [object String]
```

you'll get *[object String]*.